# CloudFormation Stacks with Exported Values and Taskcat

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, automated-tests, aws-cloudformation

I have a bunch of stacks I'm trying to test with Taskcat in our CI pipeline, but some of these stacks rely on other stacks and their exported values.

Does Taskcat have the capability to wait for other stacks in the tests section of the config to complete first before deploying other stacks in the list?

I'm using a taskcat config similar to this:

```
project:
  name: cfn-test
  regions:
    - us-east-1
tests:
  test-template-with-exported-values:
    parameters:
      EnvironmentId: ci
    template: ./test-template-1.yml
  test-template-using-exported-values:
    parameters:
      EnvironmentId: ci
    template: ./test-template-2.yml
```

The second test will fail immediately with a similar error shown below:

```
No export named SomeExportedValue found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, no, but it's in our backlog. See this GitHub issue for tracking.

- https://github.com/aws-quickstart/taskcat/issues/322

We'll post updates there, including the development build version when it becomes available.

Thx

-Andrew